# Pagination in tableView in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an API that takes a parameter called `"take"`. In viewDidLoad, I am passing 10 and I got 10 data and append them into my array of objects. I use `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method for pagination like below. I increase my takeCount by ten by and called my API again and append them to my existing array. Problem is that the `1`. object and `11`. The object is the same when I scroll to the bottom. Should I remove old data but isn't it against the logic of pagination?

**Pagination Code**

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height{
        
        self.takeCount += 10
        
        if self.takeCount <= self.sampleDataCountLimit{
            
            Service().fetchData(count: self.takeCount) { (result) in
                
                switch result{
                
                case .success(let cars):
                    
                    //self.carModel.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.carModel.append(contentsOf: cars)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        print(self.carModel.count)
                        print(self.carModel)
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your API return completely different objects with take=10 and take=20? Could it be so that it returns first 10 and first 20 objects respectively, so that the first 10 are a subset of the first 20?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev For example, I sent 10, then I type 20, and different values come after the tenth.Also when I print the self.carModel.count it returns 30.(here is the API url:http://sandbox.arabamd.com/api/v1/listing?sort=2&sortDirection=1&take=10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your API with the `take=20` parameter, it just returns first 20 items, and those 20 items also include the same items that the API would return with `take=10`. So when you append the new result to the previous result, you get duplicated items because your previous result already contained some of the items from the new result. It means that you need to replace the old data with the new data each time you call your API to avoid item duplication.

Pagination usually doesn't work like that. The API should typically accept either a range (something like `start=10&end=20`) or the page number (optionally with the page size, for example `pagesize=10&pagenumber=2`).

You should check if your API supports something like that.

Alternatively, if the number of returned items will never be huge, you can opt out from using pagination completely and fetch all items in one request.

If the number of items can be huge, but your API can only return first N items, you might keep the logic when you first fetch first N items, then 2*N items, then 3*N and so on and completely replace the data each time, but that is far from ideal.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. According to my research and some videos, there are things like page numbers. But these are not available in my API. I found the jump parameter other than the take parameter, I guess it works like this, do you think this is useful for me? URL:http://sandbox.arabamd.com/api/v1/listing?sort=0&sortDirection=1&skip=2&take=10

Comment: I guess my skip parameter works like a pageNumber :(

Comment: It seems like the combination of `skip` and `take` is just what you need. If you want to fetch 10 records a time, use `skip=0&take=10` for the first page, then `skip=10&take=10` for the second page, then `skip=20&take=10` for the third page etc.

Comment: Exactly as you said, I agree with you. Thank you so much for your time.